# how to let user create his own database asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-relationship

We're building an app where like accountant application online each user is required to have a personal database and I'm trying to find the best way to implement this or I don't know should I put all company data in one database.

So far the options are

•every company registered first time can create their own database.

•all company work on one database.

And we will use website asp.net c# hosting on smaterasp.com

Anyways, if there's a well-known way to implement this - I'd appreciate a nod in a right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just simply ask for the schema user will like to be created and then create database using the command CREATE DATABASE.

I suppose this will also help in managing the users and their accounting information more efficiently.

Comment: thanks for suggesting  you mean that the best option is create database for each user